# How to make Loading 3 dot animation in splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

Hi I am trying to make my 1st android app and I made a splash screen. However, I tried to add loading please wait at the bottom with the period increment every 2 seconds. I am not sure how to make it happen because the screen crashes because of this text.

```
   final TextView loadingText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loading_text);

    Thread splashTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                int splashTime = 0;
                while(splashTime < 6000){

                    sleep(100);

                        if(splashTime < 2000){
                            loadingText.setText("Loading.");
                        }
                        else if(splashTime >= 2000 && splashTime < 4000 ){
                            loadingText.setText("Loading..");
                        }else if (splashTime >= 4000){
                            loadingText.setText("Loading...");  
                        }
                        splashTime = splashTime + 100;

                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,myMainScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTimer.start();    
}
```

here is my logcat

```
06-12 01:36:33.646: D/HyLog(29533): I : /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, No such file or directory (2)
06-12 01:36:33.646: D/HyLog(29533): I : /data/font/config/dfactpre.dat, No such file or directory (2)
06-12 01:36:33.646: D/HyLog(29533): I : /data/font/config/sfconfig.dat, No such file or directory (2)
06-12 01:36:33.986: I/Adreno-EGL(29533): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
06-12 01:36:33.986: I/Adreno-EGL(29533): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.02
06-12 01:36:33.986: I/Adreno-EGL(29533): Build Date: 01/20/14 Mon
06-12 01:36:33.986: I/Adreno-EGL(29533): Local Branch: PMH2-KK_3.5-RB1-AU61-554722-586267-set2
06-12 01:36:33.986: I/Adreno-EGL(29533): Remote Branch: 
06-12 01:36:33.986: I/Adreno-EGL(29533): Local Patches: 
06-12 01:36:33.986: I/Adreno-EGL(29533): Reconstruct Branch: 
06-12 01:36:34.026: D/OpenGLRenderer(29533): Enabling debug mode 0
06-12 01:36:34.096: I/ActivityManager(29533): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42b1e788 time:14063098
06-12 01:36:34.336: W/dalvikvm(29533): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ae6e48)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2388
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533): Process: com.sachinda.myfirstapp, PID: 29533
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6347)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:871)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16472)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6817)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3947)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3805)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3780)
06-12 01:36:34.336: E/AndroidRuntime(29533):    at com.sachinda.myfirstapp.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:45)
06-12 01:36:36.316: I/Process(29533): Sending signal. PID: 29533 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is crashing because you are modifying ui component on a non UI thread add method like

```
private void setText(final CharSequence text) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading_text)).setText(text);
        }
    });
}
```

and modify your code to use that method

```
while(splashTime < 6000){

     sleep(100);

     if(splashTime < 2000){
         setText("Loading.");
     }
     else if(splashTime >= 2000 && splashTime < 4000 ){
         setText("Loading..");
     }else if (splashTime >= 4000){
         setText("Loading...");
     }
          splashTime = splashTime + 100;

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have achieved Loading 3 dots using `coroutines` `lifecycle` scope and recursion. Check out the below code. isCallAttended is `boolean` by default is `false`. Then you can set it `true` later in logic so that you could cancel `coroutine`.

```
private fun delayCallingAnimation() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            if(isCallAttended) {
                this.cancel()
                return@launch
            }
            delay(1000)
            mBinding.incomingCallView.tvCalling.text = "Calling."
            delay(1000)
            mBinding.incomingCallView.tvCalling.text = "Calling.."
            delay(1000)
            mBinding.incomingCallView.tvCalling.text = "Calling..."

            delayCallingAnimation()
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing here is updating the UI elements inside a thread, which isn't allowed!

What you will have to do is use Handlers:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Code here will run in UI thread
    }
});
```

This will solve the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

May be it helps anybody :) I found 2 solutions how animate dots in `TextView` ending ("...").

##### Common code

Common function for both solutions

```
private fun getDotAnimator(
    textView: TextView,
    dotCount: Int,
    list: List<CharSequence>
): ValueAnimator {
    val valueTo = dotCount + 1

    return ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, valueTo).apply {
        this.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        this.duration = textView.context.resources.getInteger(R.integer.dots_anim_time).toLong()
        this.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        this.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART

        addUpdateListener {
            val value = it.animatedValue as? Int


            /**
             * Sometimes [ValueAnimator] give a corner value.
             */
            if (value == null || value == valueTo) return@addUpdateListener

            textView.text = list.getOrNull(value)
        }
    }
}
```

In XML:

```
<string name="dot" translatable="false">.</string>

<integer name="dots_anim_time">1200</integer>
```

##### First solution: simple adding dots to string end

```
fun getDotsAnimator(textView: TextView?, @StringRes stringId: Int): ValueAnimator? {
    val context = textView?.context ?: return null

    val simpleText = context.getString(stringId)
    val dotText = context.getString(R.string.dot)
    val dotCount = 3

    val textList = mutableListOf<String>()
    for (i in 0 until dotCount + 1) {
        val text = StringBuilder(simpleText).apply {
            repeat(i) { append(dotText) }
        }.toString()

        textList.add(text)
    }

    return getDotAnimator(textView, dotCount, textList)
}
```

But it has disadvantage. If in your XML file `TextView` has `android:gravity="center"` it will looks ugly. Because text in `textList` has different `lenght` and also has different `center`. Use this solution only with `android:gravity="start"`.

##### Second solution: use spannable string

```
fun getDotsSpanAnimator(textView: TextView?, @StringRes stringId: Int): ValueAnimator? {
    val context = textView?.context ?: return null

    val simpleText = context.getString(stringId)
    val dotText = context.getString(R.string.dot)
    val dotCount = 3

    val resultText = StringBuilder(simpleText).apply {
        repeat(dotCount) { append(dotText) }
    }.toString()

    val textList = mutableListOf<SpannableString>()
    for (i in 0 until dotCount + 1) {
        val spannable = SpannableString(resultText)

        val start = resultText.length - (dotCount - i)
        val end = resultText.length
        val flag = Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        spannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT), start, end, flag)

        textList.add(spannable)
    }

    return getDotAnimator(textView, dotCount, textList)
}
```

This solution will work perfect with every `android:gravity`.

##### Use in code

```
private val dotsAnimator by lazy {
    getDotsSpanAnimator(loadingText, R.string.dialog_text_loading)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    dotsAnimator?.start()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    dotsAnimator?.pause()
}
```

##### In addition

I wrote an article with result images, may be it will be more clear for understanding: [medium](https://medium.com/@serjantarbuz/animation-of-ellipsis-79d6832d45c8)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i am late to answer but this will surely help someone else, this simple Library - **https://github.com/rajputkapil/textviewdotsanimation** available on `github` can help you to show 3 dots animation by calling simply its custom view class `TextAndAnimationView`, count of dots can be increased or decreased just by calling `app:numberOfDots="count of dots in Integer"`

Comment: you cannot alter the font with this library making it not as effective of a solution